# What is the lifecycle for NSLayoutContraint's in UIView subclasses?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I wanted to understand how to customize the layout of any `UIControl`'s subviews, so I started to play around with an `UIButton`. I've found that I can subclass it and override `layoutSubviews` and then say which frames I want for each subview (namely its `UILabel` and `UIImageView`). But then I read this in the `UIView` reference

> layoutSubviews - Implement this method if you need more precise control over the layout of your subviews than either the constraint or autoresizing behaviors provide.

So, I thought I might just add some constraints for the label and the imageView, but then I found some constraints already existed and conflicted with mine (specifically, the `[image]-0-[label]` one). By debugging (printing the `constraints` property of all my views & subviews, also calling `constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:` on everyone) I also found out that constraints like that are not created, or at least they do not show up, until I add my own. Not even calling `layoutIfNeeded`, if I don't add some of my own constraints first. I looked it up but couldn't find if there is a method (such as `updateConstraints`) that creates this that I can prevent by overriding, or at least a way to obtain a reference to these constraints and delete the ones I don't want.

I'm very confused and couldn't find any official apple doc on when and how are an `UIButton`'s inner constraints created.